# Draw marker (tag) using GDI

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to create custom control that will be used to present timeline.
I found nice looking design on net:

[image]

and I started coding, couple of minutes later I had this:

[image]

As You can see big marker looks quite good, but smallest could look better.

My current code responsible for marker drawing looks like this:

```
    enum Position
    {
        Left,
        Right
    }

    private void DrawMarker(Graphics gfx, Rectangle Bounds, int CornerRadius, Pen DrawPen, Position direction)
    {
        GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath();
        gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y + 0, CornerRadius, CornerRadius), 270, 45); //tr

        if(direction==Position.Right)
            gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius + 40, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height / 2, CornerRadius, CornerRadius), 315, 90); //right

        gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius), 45, 45); //br
        gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(Bounds.X + 0, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius), 90, 90); //bl
        gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(Bounds.X + 0, Bounds.Y + 0, CornerRadius, CornerRadius), 180, 90); //tl
        gfxPath.CloseAllFigures();
        //gfx.FillPath(new SolidBrush(FillColor), gfxPath);
        gfx.DrawPath(DrawPen, gfxPath);
    }
```

I need a way to improve look of those markers.
I think that problem are angles of arcs in top right and bottom right corners.
I have them set to 45, but this looks bad if markes is small.

Angles on left side will be always 90, but angles on right and on marked need to be calculated.

How should I modify my function to calculate arcs correctly?

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this.

Comment: Clearly your math is borken.  A simple way to avoid having to do the math is start with a single marker and just rescale it.

Comment: @HighCore I would like to use WPF for this, but unfortunately project is build in WinForms and this control must work in WinForms.

Comment: @misiu you can host WPF content in an existing winforms application via the `ElementHost`.

Comment: @Hans what do You mean by saying rescale? I don't need to calculate position of every corner? I need a way to draw marker that will change it's height depending on text.

Comment: @HighCore I know I can add WPF controls to WinForms, problem is I'm not a WPF person and this might be hard for first thing to build using WPF

Comment: @HighCore WPF? Pfft! :P

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the "nose" of the tag rectangle isn't compensating for the radius size, which is causing the "nose" to dip downward:

```
r.Y + r.Height / 2 - radius / 2
```

I also shortened the width from 40 to 20.

```
private void DrawMarker(Graphics gfx, Rectangle r, int radius, Pen drawPen, Position direction) {
  using (GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath()) {
    gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(r.X + r.Width - radius, r.Y + 0, radius, radius), 270, 45); //tr
    if (direction == Position.Right) {
      gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(r.X + r.Width - radius + 20, r.Y + r.Height / 2 - radius / 2, radius, radius), 315, 90); //right
    }
    gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(r.X + r.Width - radius, r.Y + r.Height - radius, radius, radius), 45, 45); //br
    gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(r.X + 0, r.Y + r.Height - radius, radius, radius), 90, 90); //bl
    gfxPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(r.X + 0, r.Y + 0, radius, radius), 180, 90); //tl
    gfxPath.CloseAllFigures();
    gfx.DrawPath(drawPen, gfxPath);
  }
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGray, 2)) {
    DrawMarker(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(16, 16, 100, 32), 8, pen, Position.Right);
  }
  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for "nose" fix :) I'll check it right away. My problem isn't nose position but angles on right side (side where nose is) because right now I have hard-coded 45 degrees, but I think this should be calculated based on height of marker. If marker is high then angle is larger, if it is low the angle is larger. Same for nose arc angle. I have problem with calculating that.

Comment: @Misiu I don't think it's an angle issue.  When I look at the original image, it looks like a distance issue.  For the "nose" distance, try `r.X + r.Width - radius + r.Height / 2`.  I'm adding half the height of the rectangle to make the nose stick more when it's bigger.